# Why is this statement included in the stored procedure definition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I got nailed today by a typo, its a simple typo when I defined a script to create a stored procedure under `Sql Server 2005`, I forgot a `GO` statement in between the `END` statement and the `GRANT` statement, this lead to the `GRANT` statement being included in the stored procedure definition and running at the end of the stored procedure (verified with SQL Profiler).

Here is the code:

```
USE [TestGround]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[FooProc]
AS 
    BEGIN

    SELECT * FROM dbo.Foo
    END

-- a GO statement is missing here..   
GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[Foo] TO dbo
```

I understand that `GO` signifies the end of a batch, but I was surprised to see that the `GRANT` statement was included in the stored procedure, I've never forgotten the `GO` statement before so haven't seen this issue.

Could someone please explain to me why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leave out the `BEGIN` / `END` pair: the definition doesn't end at END. It continues until the end of the file or a `GO`, whichever comes first.

Comment: I thought this was the answer, but sometimes its just best to clarify.